# How do I know which objects I can use the keyword USING in C#?

Tags: c#, using

Given that the keyword "using" should always be used when applicable, I wanted to go with that. The problem is, how do I know which objects I can use USING?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591000/identify-idisposable-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tools like [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [CodeRush](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) to identify code where you don't call `Dispose`/use `using` on objects implementing `IDisposable`. They will warn you in this case.

Also, in Visual Studio, you can use the [Object Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exy1facf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to see which types implement `IDisposable`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Objects that implement [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) can be used with the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) construct.

You can view the class' documentation, its definition in code, or use the object explorer in Visual Studio to find implemented interfaces.

Also, if you should try to use a type that does not implement `IDisposable` in a `using` block, the compiler will emit a warning. This means you can always try it if in doubt, if the compiler complains, you should not use `using`. However, you should always be aware of which objects you use are `IDisposable` and treat them accordingly.

The primary purpose of `IDisposable` (though I have seen it used (and mis-used) for other stuff), is to ensure timely deallocation of unmanaged resources. Unmanaged resources, as the term is used here, might be a hardware device handle, files, streams, connections, etc. Anything, you would like to ensure gets disposed as soon as you are finished with the resource, instead of waiting for the GC to kick in.

Comment: But how do I know if they implement IDisposable?

Comment: You look it up in the documentation (or by using the object explorer to view implemented interfaces).

Comment: @Testifier: Go to that class's signature. For eg. `TextReader` or `BinaryReader`.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that in most cases Classes implementing [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) should be used within [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) blocks.

To see if a class does implement `IDisposable`, you can just look at it's definition. Code style analysis tools like FXCop will also alert you if `IDiposable` implementations are not disposed correctly.

Comment: That's not true.  Only `IDisposable` objects can be in a using block.  It will be a compiler error otherwise.  Additionally, there are cases where you will want to dispose of an `IDisposeable` object without using a `using`, so saying you should *always* us a `using` isn't true.

Comment: It's also not true that *using* is only useful for unmanaged resources.  It is useful anytime you want IDisposable.Dispose() to execute, whether or not an Exception was thrown in the code block.  Sometimes you want managed cleanup code to run deterministically.

Answer (score -1):

Use it for local instances of all classes that implement `IDisposable`. They have a `Dispose` method.